# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, gwt, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem in using of my own Database server with Google web application.

Am using eclips (java EE IDE), installed all google plugins init, and develop a sample google web aplication , deployed it into web.Its working correctly.

Now i want to use my own Database in my app.(MYSQL installed in localhost).
Here am using Hibernate to connect with database. All required jar file are placed in lib directory which is in WEB-INF folder.

When i run my application it gives an error like ..

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /Home
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at base.Trackerlogin.service(Trackerlogin.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:289)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:314)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:288)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:332)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:419)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.<init>(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:33)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:88)
    ... 46 more
Apr 26, 2013 10:37:22 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:289)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:314)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:288)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:332)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:419)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.<init>(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:33)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:88)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at base.Trackerlogin.service(Trackerlogin.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Apr 26, 2013 10:37:22 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider close
INFO: cleaning up connection pool: null
```

Please give any Idea to achieve this one....

Comment: Your Google security Manager Settings is what causing this error.

Comment: ohh really ,, pls how could i solve this one Ravi

Comment: Ramesh, please check Manolo's answer. It seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Ya well, In the initial stage of project development, maintaining Google Database (cloud SQL)is not possible.
We have our own Server(MYSQL).So i want to connect with that database using URL(host name) , username and password..
If i success in localhost then i will change my connection to Server Databas.. 
So is there any alternate choice is there Ravi Trivedi..

Comment: ya Ravi... I wana run my app in that way..

Answer (score 6):

Do you use Hibernate 4.3.1 Final ?

Hibernate's `DriverManagerConnectionProvider` tries to create new Threads, which is not allowed on GAE. I also had this issue.

Checking out Google's [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java) on GitHub told me that using Hibernate 4.2.0.Final works fine. I tried to run the same example with Hibernate 4.3.1 and got the same Exception. But with 4.2 it's running just as expected.

I'm gonna downgrade Hibernate in my App and see..

Comment: Hello Gaël, indeed Hibernate tries to create Threads (tried version 4.3.6.Final). Is there any other solution than downgrading?.. There should be an option to completely disable connection pooling because this is the best option when working from Google App Engine.

Is there an option to turn of thread creation in new(er) Hibernate versions?

Answer (score 4):

This week i tried to use **Hibernate 4.3.6.Final** in a **Google App Engine / Google Cloud Sql project** and ran into the above described problem (**java.security.AccessControlException**). In earlier GAE/GCS projects i used Hibernate 4.3.0.Beta3 without any problems.

As Gaël Oberson already stated above, the problem is the new implementation of the default connection pool **DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl** in Hibernate. This connection pool tries to spawn new Threads with **Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor**;

```
executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
        new Runnable() {...}
```

[This is not allowed on Google App Engine;](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/)

> A Java application can create a new thread, but there are some
>   restrictions on how to do it. These threads can't "outlive" the
>   request that creates them.

The actual problem is the Hibernate configuration which doesn't allow the use of **no connection pool**. According to Google [this connection pool is even not necessary on GAE/GCS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#connections);

> How to best manage your database connections depends on your use case.
>   For example, if the time to create a new database connection is
>   greater than checking and reusing an existing connection, then we
>   recommend you use connection pooling. Conversely, if the time to
>   create a new connection is about the same as testing if an existing
>   connection is alive and reusing it, then we recommend that you create
>   a new connection to service each HTTP request, and reuse it for the
>   duration of the request. In particular, the latter case may apply when
>   you connect from Google App Engine to Google Cloud SQL.

**summarized; we don't need connection pooling on GAE/GCS, but Hibernate doesn't provide a non connection pooling option out of the box.**

Because of a tight schedule i went for a quick solution; i wrote my own version of DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl. This version doesn't keep an administration of connections but just opens and closes connection on a call. There's some room for improvement because i should reuse the connection for the duration of the request ... Another solution would be the use of approved GAE Threads...

In my opinion Hibernate should provide the no pooling option for GAE/GCS developers. [I already posted this topic at the Hibernate Community](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=1036744).

Answer (score 2):

Follow this:

1. Appengine has their own version of MySQL called [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/). See the docs on how to [use your own MySQL instance during development](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide#using_the_java_development_server). Note that you can not use your own MySQL in production.
2. See the docs on how [make Cloud SQL work with Hibernate](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception while trying to use `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and got it solved by doing the following:

1. used `com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
2. changed the jdk version from jdk1.7.0_25 to jdk1.7.0_21