# Google App Engine with Hibernate java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, google-app-engine

So from other topics here and the google dev site I put together the following
- Enabled Google App Engine
- Checked SQL Cloud
- Setup my developer instance to point to MySQL
- added mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar to \eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\impl folder

This created the following VM Args for Googles rdbms

```
-Drdbms.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rent1?user=APP_WEB_RENT1 
-Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
-Drdbms.server=local -Drdbms.password="" 
-Drdbms.user="APP_WEB_RENT1" 
-Drdbms.database="rent1" 
-javaagent:C:\Tools\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar 
-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=50 
-Xmx512m 
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

So in the hibernate.cfg.xml I used the RDBMS drivers

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver</property>

        <!-- Connect to rent1 -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:google:rdbms://localhost:3306/rent1</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">APP_WEB_RENT1</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
```

So the Google app engine driver should take this now and load the MySQL driver based on my Development Instance I setup.  By what I read on Google and other sites this should work. But blows up with the following error,

Answers here [did not fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229323/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission)

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:431)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:456)
>     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:376)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.(Thread.java:652)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:572)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:610)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:924)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:333)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:594)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Executors.java:698)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
>     at
>   com.rent1.utils.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:29)
>     at com.rent1.utils.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:14)  at
>   com.rent1.utils.HibernateUtil.getInstance(HibernateUtil.java:19)  at
>   com.rent1.Rent1Servlet.doGet(Rent1Servlet.java:28)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:487)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.xml :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```