# Using HIbernate at the backend of my apps to access database

Tags: android, hibernate, android-studio, backend

I am developing my app using android studio. At the back end of the server, I use Hibernate to access the database. I keep getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:508)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.<init>(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:35)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:96)
```

The following code is to initialize it.

```
    try{
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/com/applicationctrl/mvpframework/backend/hbm/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        return cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        logger.severe("HibernateUtil Exception");
        logger.severe(exception.getMessage());
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(exception);
    }
```

Why I would get the access control exception?

Thanks
Ming

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Hibernate are you using? Try using 4.2.0.Final as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229323/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission/22104021#22104021).